# Simple Injector registration of Composite combining open and closed generic implementations

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm working on creating validation decorators for my commands, but I'm having trouble with registering the types with the Simple Injector DI container.

The case is:

- I have (for now) a single validator that should always be applied, the `DataAnnotationsCommandValidator<TCommand>`.
- I also have several validators that should be applied to specific commands. An example is  `CreateRefreshTokenCommandValidator`, which implements `ICommandValidator<CreateRefreshTokenCommand>`.

According to the [Simple Injector documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#batch-registration), one should create a `CompositeCommandValidator` in cases like these. I've mimicked the implementation mentioned in the documentation, meaning that my `ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator` still can have a dependency on `ICommandValidator<TCommand>` instead of an `IEnumerable`.

Then there is the configuration of the Simple Injector container. My configuration currently looks like this:

```
_container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ICommandValidator<>), 
    _container.RegisterAll,
    typeof (ICommandValidator<>).Assembly);

_container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ICommandValidator<>),
    typeof(DataAnnotationsCommandValidator<>));

_container.RegisterSingleOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ICommandValidator<>), 
    typeof(CompositeCommandValidator<>));
```

However, when I debug the application, only the specific validators are injected into the `CompositeCommandValidator` (I'm missing the `DataAnnotationsCommandValidator`). I've tried a few different configurations, but to no avail. How should I configure Simple Injector to get the correct behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE for Simple Injector v4:**

```
// Register validators as sequence
_container.Collection.Register(
    typeof(ICommandValidator<>),
    typeof (ICommandValidator<>).Assembly);

// Append the data annotations validator as last element to the sequence
_container.Collection.Append(
    typeof(ICommandValidator<>),
    typeof(DataAnnotationsCommandValidator<>));

// Register the composite that will wrap the sequence.
_container.Register(
    typeof(ICommandValidator<>), 
    typeof(CompositeCommandValidator<>));
```

**Original Simple Injector v2 answer:**

The `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` method will only scan the assemblies for non-generic implementations of the given interface, because open-generic implementations often need special care. There are basically two options here.

Option 1:

```
var types = OpenGenericBatchRegistrationExtensions.GetTypesToRegister(
    _container,
    typeof (ICommandValidator<>),
    AccessibilityOption.PublicTypesOnly,
    typeof (ICommandValidator<>).Assembly)
    .ToList();

types.Add(typeof(DataAnnotationsValidator<>));

_container.RegisterAll(typeof(ICommandValidator<>), types);
```

Here we use the `GetTypesToRegister` method to find all non-generic implementations, we append the open generic type to this collection and register the whole set using `RegisterAll`.

Your second option is to mix `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` with `AppendToCollection`:

```
_container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(ICommandValidator<>), 
    _container.RegisterAll,
    typeof(ICommandValidator<>).Assembly);

// using SimpleInjector.Advanced;
_container.AppendToCollection(typeof(ICommandValidator<>),
    typeof(DataAnnotationsValidator<>));
```

Comment: Thanks! Would never have guessed that. I made an edit to your answer, as it was close to being completely correct.

Comment: @Larrifax: The way you need to register this is a direct result of the design decision to split normal registrations from registrations of collections.